# Best token implementation for APIs from servers to servers

Tags: web-apis

I have several servers that play in their own roles like a log server, a database server, a user data server, and etc. And I've placed a proxy server for incoming requests to fetch a different type of data from those servers.

The network flows simply look something like this below.

[image]

As you can see, there's no direct requests from public networks. My proxy is going to deal with the requests from internal servers only. But, for standard security guidances out there, and in case of the internal servers taken by hackers, which would be highly unlikely to happen, I still stongly feel like to implement a secure way to prevent the unauthorized accesses to our APIs.

So I'm looking for a lightweight, reliable way to protect my APIs using token authentication. I've come up with several methods to do this.

1. OAuth2
2. SAML
3. ASP.NET Identity Server 3 ( Can't implement upper versions, I don't use ASP.NET Core X )

However, I feel like those could be over-design for my usage.

**Question**

Is there anything that is more simpler than them? or should I just implement one of them without further considerations?

Comment: Are you asking for a software package to install, a library to use in your implementation – or a suitable technology to use?

Comment: @lzzy Anything that could fit right into my environment. Or confirming that IdentityServer is the way to go will be enough for me too if given proper reasons.

Comment: Anything what? Library so you can implement it yourself, ready-to-use software? Keep in mind this site is about recommending *software* – not technologies, algorithms etc. So we need criteria like the OS it shall run on (or the programming language in case of libraries), and how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions.